# How to use aggregate function in spring data mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have a json data like

```
{ 
  "organizationId" : "org1",
  "userId" : "user1",
  "transactionNo" : "342"
},
{ 
  "organizationId" : "org1",
  "userId" : "user1",
  "transactionNo" : "343"
},
{ 
  "organizationId" : "org1",
  "userId" : "user1",
  "transactionNo" : "344"
},
{
  "organizationId" : "org1",
  "userId" : "user2",
  "transactionNo" : "324"
},
{
  "organizationId" : "org1",
  "userId" : "user2",
  "transactionNo" : "325"
},
{
  "organizationId" : "org1",
  "userId" : "user3",
  "transactionNo" : "324"
},
{
  "organizationId" : "org2",
  "userId" : "user1",
  "transactionNo" : "324"
},
{
  "organizationId" : "org2",
  "userId" : "user2",
  "transactionNo" : "324"
},
{
  "organizationId" : "org3",
  "userId" : "user1",
  "transactionNo" : "324"
}
```

So i have all this records where one organisation will have multiple users and one user is performing multiple activities.
My requirement is to provide "organisationId" and get the no of users for that organisation. For this example, if i provide "org1", i should get "3"

I have tried method "getDistinctUserIdByOrganisationId(String organisationId)" in spring data mongo repository. But its not working. what to write in @Query()?
How do i solve it with other options? i am new to mongo. i have previously worked on mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use match, group and count to get the answer.
Please go though this [link](https://www.hoab.fr/spring-data-and-mongodb-aggregation-groupby). It has a simple example that may help you.

Comment: so it can't be done using MongoRepository of spring using @query because I already have the repository interface, it doesn't look good to have one more repsoitory for same model class or writing a MongoTemplate in service class.